# ARC + Dealloc is not called

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I am little confuse because my dealloc is not called in ARC. I have using storyboard in my application.

Case 1: My`dealloc` called when i use all `IBOutlet` from storyboard

Case 2: My `dealloc` is not called when i try to use `alloc` and `init` methods in `UIViewController`. such as below.

```
 UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileDetailView" bundle:nil];
        __weak ProfileDetailView *detailview = (ProfileDetailView *)vc.view;
        detailview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        vc = nil;
....Set value in object.....

[self.view addSubview:detailview];;
        detailview = nil;
```

Can you explain why `dealloc` is not called? and How can i able to achieve to call `dealloc`?

Thanks

Comment: You are making things more complicated that necessary with `_weak` and setting variables to nil. In general Objective-C handles object lifetimes just fine behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of ARC is that an object's **retain count** should theoretically be 1 in order for it to be deallocated. When you execute:

```
[self.view addSubview:detailview];;
```

Your `self.view` increments `detailview`'s retain count by 1 when it adds it to `view.subviews`. Logically, when `self.view` removes `detailview`, the retain count is decremented by 1.

Again, this is a **theoretical** perspective. The reality is usually:

## ***INSANE.***

No one really knows how the mysterious Objective-C runtime works! (just kidding the whole source code is available online.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but that is happening in my case... and memory is remaining after pop my view controller. Yes, you are correct, I need to remove that from my view but where?

Comment: Since `detailview` is `_weak` and `vc` is released there is no retain on what `detail view` points to. It is dead by the time it is being added to `addSubview`.

Comment: @Zaph: How is it dead? `detailview = nil;` is called after `[self.view addSubview:detailview];;`

Comment: Perhaps it is just INSANE, it seem that INSANE is what makes Objective-C work. OK, where is `detail view` retained?

Comment: BTW, not theoretical, the retain count never goes to zero.

Comment: @Zaph: So you're saying that any object declared with the `_weak` modifier dies immediately?

Comment: As long as something else has a strong reference to the object it exists. If there is no other strong reference it does die immediately. Note, the memory still exists but at some point that will be reused so it is non-deterministic.

Comment: Yep, **insane** is the word.

Comment: @orkenstein There are basically three choices for memory management. 1. The programmer does it all: C; C++, Assembly -- lot's of errors. 2. Garbage collection, some form of mark-sweep: Java, C# -- hiccups at nondeterministic times. 3. Reference counted: Objective-C, Python, deterministic, no hiccups possible retain cycles. Take your choice. Reference counting with autorelease: Insanely Great.

Comment: @Zaph, yeah, and I enjoy it very much. But sometimes you want to connect obj-C with JIT environment (UNITY for example). Than's time for pain in your ass...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I am able to called my dealloc function when view controller pop. For achieving that, we need to remove my added subviews from my view when user tapped on back button.